# Have any method to get post_type before load the contents in wordpress admin

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to get the `post_type` before fetching the data from database. I have hooks for getting it.
I used:

```
add_action( 'admin_head', 'get_type' );
```

But this hook not working at page load. I also used:

```
global $current_screen;
```

within the `admin_init` action. Is there anyway to get post type before post query runs?

Comment: <?php $screen = get_current_screen(); ?> The function returns null if called from the admin_init hook. It should be OK to use in a later hook.

Comment: What admin section you are talking about?

Comment: i want to run some action before custom post type data fetch from db... what hook we can use for that

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `init`

```
add_action('init','my_post_type_func');
```

Runs after WordPress has finished loading but before any headers are sent.

Comment: yes it also not working 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen